# Repair or replace sillcock

Tags: leak, plumbing-fixture, hose

I have a frost proof sillcock that is only a few years old. It is leaking - and the issue is that I can't find a way to take it apart and check for a bad washer where the leak is coming from. The leak is not coming from the hose connection but the ring above it. Is there a way to fix this or do I need to replace the whole thing?

[image: Leaking where the arrow is pointing]

Comment: That looks like a threaded-on vacuum breaker. Sometimes they have a thumbscrew to keep them from accidentally loosening when you remove the hose. Check for that, and then try grabbing the ring with the label and loosening. Then it’s a simple replacement.

Comment: @TimB OK, thanks. I will look for a screw. I tried loosening before but it didn't budge and I didn't want to use too much force and possibly break it.

Comment: @TimB If OP finds a thumbscrew then it could be a simple matter of tightening it actually; replacement may be unnecessary.

Comment: Here’s an example: https://youtu.be/cp0uXG7DVDY. The thumbscrew doesn’t play a role in water sealing, other than preventing inadvertent loosening of the device.

Comment: @TimB The thumbscrew is sometimes designed so the head snaps off after the screw is tightened as an anti-tamper feature also preventing *intentional* loosening/removal of the device. It might appear as a small round hole plugged with a pin. If this is found drilling out the pin (screw, really) may work, but if not one might have to resort to destroying the vacuum breaker or replacing the sillcock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an accessory vacuum breaker that screws on.  They're required by Code, so it was probably sold as part of the sillcock.

A new sillcock will have a vacuum breaker built right into it.

*Since I also see a manifold in that picture, you may want to review the literature on use of those with sillcocks and vacuum breakers*.  E.G. [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195532/how-does-everyone-set-up-sprinkler-timer-with-residential-outdoor-faucets).

Comment: This is an "Arrow" brand sillcock, and the vacuum breakers on one that new have special "one way threads" and don't come off.  You can cut them off, but a new breaker is about the same cost as a new sillcock.

Comment: This actually did screw off - it just took a little more force than I originally applied. It has a washer inside - I could probably replace that, but I'll just replace the whole part.